# Python - GPG decrypt works but GNUPG doesn't

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I'm using pythons gnupg to decrypt a file I've downloaded with python:

```
        gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/myname/.gnupg")
    with open('updates/'+filelist[i],'r') as f:
        print "Decrypting "+fn
        status=gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase="passphrase",output='updates/'+fn)

    print 'ok: ', status.ok
    print 'stderr: ',status.stderr
```

This fails saying 'secret key not available'.  However when I run gpg -d filename from terminal the file decrypts without any errors.  I've used gpg -K and checked that the secret certificate / key used to encrypt the file is imported + trusted etc.

This is all running on Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Can anyone suggest how I can get around this error?

Comment: Title looks inconsistent with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that GnuPG is the "real" name of `gpg`, which is only the name of the binary. The python API is called python-gnupg.

The problem will most probably be caused by **missing access privileges**. As you already realized, each system user has its own GnuPG home directory (thus you provided another user's GnuPG-directory), not accessible by others. Make sure your web server user (probably `www-data`) has access to `/home/myname/.gnupg`, better export the private key and reimport it from within the webserver's user (GnuPG does not like extensive access rights and might send a warning or deny to run at all otherwise).

You can test if that really is the problem by running `sudo -u www-data 'gpg --home-dir /home/myname/.gnupg -d filename` (thus, run `gpg` under the web server's user).