# Why using python-gnupg makes .xlsx file unreadable?

Tags: python, encryption, xlsx, gnupg

I have some problems with python-gnupg package.
I need to decrypt an encrypted .xlsx file, do something with it and then encrypt it back again. So I've written a small script to see how it would work and.. it doesn't.

Unfortuanately, searching SO doesn't return many answers (somehow python-gpg related questions are not very well received here), nor does googling. The ones I've found which seemed relevant but aren't: [SO: privilege related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140089/python-gpg-decrypt-works-but-gnupg-doesnt), [python-gnupg group: add str to crypt object](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-gnupg/e6vv1m68k4g).

The problem can be put as follows:

1. The program encrypts and decrypts the `.xlsx` file, but it is unreadable after the process.
2. If I encrypt the file using command line, it can't be decrypted from python. Instead I see the following error:

   ```
   File "/gnupg-2.0.2-py3.5.egg/gnupg/_parsers.py", line 1419 in _handle_status raise ValueError("Unknown status message: %r" % key)
   ValueError: Unknown status message: 'FAILURE'
   ```
3. Code works fine with text files, but if I'd encrypt such a file using CLI, decryption from within python results in the same error as above.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='~/.gnupg/')

with open('echo.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.encrypt(
        f, '5955128B',
        output='echo.xlsx.gpg')

print ('ok: ', status.ok)
print ('status: ', status.status)
print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)

a = input('press any key to continue')

with open('echo.xslx.gpg', 'rb',) as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(
        f, passphrase='passphrase', output='echo2.xslx')

print ('ok: ', status.ok)
print ('status: ', status.status)
print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)
```

I'm on python 3.5, python-gnupg 2.0.2, GnuPG 2.0.29.

I would really appreciate some help on this, I desperately need this to work.

Comment: I found a way around this: when one uses (the original) fork by [Vinay Sajip](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg) and an older version of gnupg everything works fine. NB it isn't obvious that there are two forks. If you want to be sure: Vinay's fork uses lower numbers (ver. 0.38 right now) and is called python-gnupg, not gnupg.